# How do pack and unpack guesses the character encoding when converting to and from utf8?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, pack, ruby-1.8.7

Suppose I want to convert `"\xBD"` to UTF-8.

If I use `pack` & `unpack`, I'll get `½`:

```
puts "\xBD".unpack('C*').pack('U*')    #=> ½
```

as `"\xBD"` is `½` in ISO-8859-1.

BUT `"\xBD"` is `œ` in ISO-8859-9.

My question is: why `pack` used ISO-8859-1 instead of ISO-8859-9 to convert the char to UTF-8? Is there some way to configure that character encoding?

I know I can use `Iconv` in Ruby 1.8.7, and `String#encode` in 1.9.2, but I'm curious about `pack` because I use it in some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with how `\xBD` is represented in ISO-8859-x. The critical part is the `pack` into UTF-8.

The `pack` receives `[189]`. The code point 189 is defined in UTF-8 (more precisely, Unicode) as being `½`. Don't think of this as the Unicode spec writers for "preferring" ISO-8859-1 over ISO-8859-9. They had to make a choice of what code point represented `½` and they just chose 189.

Since you're trying to learn more about `pack`/`unpack`, let me explain more:

When you `unpack` with the `C` directive, ruby interprets the string as ascii-8bit, and extracts the ascii codes. In this case `\xBD` translates to `0xBD` a.k.a. `189`. This is a really basic conversion.

When you `pack` with the `U` directive, ruby will look up in its UTF-8 translation table to see what codepoints map to each of the integers in the array.

`pack`/`unpack` have very specific behavior depending on the directives you provide it. I suggest reading up on ruby-doc.org. Some of the directives still don't make sense to me, so don't be discouraged.

Comment: I've read [ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack) before, and there are other two good tutorials about Perl's `pack/unpack` [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=224666) and [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html). I'm going to study them later. I hadn't found encoding information anywhere, but now I got the point. Thank you!

Comment: @SonySantos A good primer on encodings and character sets: http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/the_unicode_character_set_and_encodings . Once you're done with that the table of contents link has even more articles.

Comment: "Some of the directives still don't make sense to me, so don't be discouraged.", so true!